# EXTJS editor datefield not rendered after add it to grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

When I add an editor with datefield as Xtype to my grid, the datefield does not render.

My problem is that I have to validate a daterange based on two dates. When I click in one of the dafields check the value of the other picker, but I can not get the value of the other datefield because is not render (the datefield renders after click it).

Moreover, if the validator crashes with the undefined, the datefield gets mad and the position on the DOM changes randomly.

The code is something like this:

```
{ xtype: 'form',
defaults: {
     labelAlign: 'top',
     width: '95%'
},
items: [
     Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
          id: '<the id>',
          selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
              singleSelect: false,
              sortable: false,
              checkOnly: true
          }),
          store: myStore,
          plugins: {
              ptype: 'celledititing',
              pluginId: 'celledit',
          },
          columns: [
              { text: 'Field 1', dataIndex: 'FIELD_1', width: '25%' },
              { text: 'Field 2', dataIndex: 'FIELD_2', width: '25%' },
              { text: 'Date 1', dataIndex: 'DATE_1', width: '25%',
                renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y'),
                editor: {
                     xtype: 'datefield',
                     id: '<date id>',
                     vtype: 'daterange',
                     endDateField: '<date 2 id>',
                     dateRangeMin: '',
                     flex: 1
               },
               { text: 'Date 2', dataIndex: 'DATE_2', width: '25%',
                 renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y'),
                 editor: {
                     xtype: 'datefield',
                     id: '<date 2 id>',
                     vtype: 'daterange',
                     startDateField: '<date id>',
                     dateRangeMin: '',
                     flex: 1
               }
          ],
          plugins: {
              ptype: 'cellediting',
              clicksToEdit: 1
          },
          height: 200
      })
      ]
 }
```

Greetings-

Answer (score 0):

You are right. you cannot get value from other datefield because it is not rendered, you can save field in grid's property and validate it manually on grid's `validateedit` event. here is almost ready snippet, you just need to add your validate logic in grid's `validateedit` listener

```js
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {

    data: [{
        FIELD_1: 'voluptas',
        FIELD_2: 'consequatur',
        DATE_1: '12/15/2013',
        DATE_2: '4/18/2008'
    }, {
        FIELD_1: 'eveniet',
        FIELD_2: 'modi',
        DATE_1: '4/7/2008',
        DATE_2: '7/26/2004'
    }, {
        FIELD_1: 'ea',
        FIELD_2: 'voluptas',
        DATE_1: '7/3/2012',
        DATE_2: '9/2/2008'
    }, {
        FIELD_1: 'minima',
        FIELD_2: 'iste',
        DATE_1: '3/3/2002',
        DATE_2: '7/15/2013'
    }, {
        FIELD_1: 'consequatur',
        FIELD_2: 'beatae',
        DATE_1: '3/3/2013',
        DATE_2: '10/20/2014'
    }],
    fields: [{
        name: 'FIELD_1'
    }, {
        name: 'FIELD_2'
    }, {
        name: 'DATE_1',
        type: 'date'
    }, {
        name: 'DATE_2',
        type: 'date'
    }]
});



Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
    title: "test",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'form',
        defaults: {
            labelAlign: 'top',
            width: '95%'
        },
        items: [
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                id: '<the id>',
                selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
                    singleSelect: false,
                    sortable: false,
                    checkOnly: true
                }),
                store: myStore,
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'celledititing',
                    pluginId: 'celledit',
                },
                parseDate: function(value) {
                    var me = this,
                        val = value,
                        altFormats = me.altFormats,
                        altFormatsArray = me.altFormatsArray,
                        i = 0,
                        len;

                    if (value && !Ext.isDate(value)) {
                        val = me.safeParse(value, me.format);

                        if (!val && altFormats) {
                            altFormatsArray = altFormatsArray || altFormats.split('|');
                            len = altFormatsArray.length;
                            for (; i < len && !val; ++i) {
                                val = me.safeParse(value, altFormatsArray[i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // If configured to snap, snap resulting parsed Date to the closest increment.
                    if (val && me.snapToIncrement) {
                        val = new Date(Ext.Number.snap(val.getTime(), me.increment * 60 * 1000));
                    }
                    return val;
                },
                listeners: {
                    validateedit: {
                        fn: function(editor, e) {
                            var grid = editor.grid;
                            var date = grid.parseDate(e.value);

                            if(e.field=="DATE_1"){
                              field = grid.startField
                            }else{
                              field = grid.endField
                            }
                            if (!date) {
                                return false;
                            }
                            ///// validate your Fields HERE
                            
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                },
                startField: null,
                endField: null,
                    columns: [{
                              text: 'Field 1',
                              dataIndex: 'FIELD_1',
                              width: '25%'
                          }, {
                              text: 'Field 2',
                              dataIndex: 'FIELD_2',
                              width: '25%'
                          }, {
                              text: 'Date 1',
                              dataIndex: 'DATE_1',
                              width: '25%',
                              renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y'),
                              editor: new Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Date",{
                                xtype: 'datefield',
                                id: '<date id>',
                                dateRangeMin: '',
                                flex: 1,
                                listeners: {
                                    change: function(field) {
                                        this.up("gridpanel").startField = field;
                                    }
                                },
                              })
                          }, {
                              text: 'Date 2',
                              dataIndex: 'DATE_2',
                              width: '25%',
                              renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d/m/Y'),
                              editor: {
                                  xtype: 'datefield',
                                  id: '<date 2 id>',
                                  dateRangeMin: '',
                                  dateRangeMax:'',
                                  flex: 1,
                                  listeners: {
                                      change: function(field) {
                                          this.up("gridpanel").endField = field;
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }],
                
                plugins: {
                    ptype: 'cellediting',
                    clicksToEdit: 1
                },
                height: 200
            })
        ]
    }]
})
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/ext-all-dev.js"></script>
    
    </head>
  </html>
```